# Highlighting Active Buttons in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a newbie question regarding HTML and styling. My HTML/JS code currently works in that the clicked "button" stays a certain color (light blue) so the user knows which page is being displayed:

[image]

However, it seems clunky because I'm putting logic (albeit UI logic) in a DOM element. I'm new enough at UI styling to not know if this is the correct way. Is this how these things are supposed to be done? This is my implementation:

CSS:

```
.navBar a:hover {
        background: #F0F5F5;
    }

.navBar a.active {
        background: #D6EBFF;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="navBar" style="display:inline; float:right; margin-top:30px; margin-right:30px">
  <ul>
    <li><a ng-class="{'active' : activePage === 'main'}" ng-click="activePage = 'main'" href="#/main">Main</a></li>
    <li><a ng-class="{'active' : activePage === 'recipes'}" ng-click="activePage = 'recipes'" href="#/recipes">Recipes</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When a link is clicked, a string literal is set and then the CSS class is used based on that string literal. I feel like I'm overthinking this.

Comment: which router you are using? angular ui-router?

Comment: Hi Bob, there's no one "correct" way to style a User Interface; that's a personal preference. Answers to that question will be highly opinionated; as such, I'd recommend asking this question on the UX Stack Exchange site, where such a question is more on-topic.

Comment: I'm using Angular's routing, $routeProvider. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @TylerH I agree that answers can be opinions, but sometimes experienced developers can look at questions like this and go: "Yeah, uh, that's totally a newbie way to do it. Here's a better approach." While it may not be considered the *one correct way*, it's still a better approach than a newbie guess.

Comment: @TylerH Before I get votes to close on yet another site, is the UX Stack Exchange site the appropriate place? That name implies that the questions are about user experience, and this is a coding/implementation approach.

Comment: @BobHorn I don't frequent the UX site that much, so I can't say with certainty that it is; I only know that they allow highly opinionated questions/answers on that site. If you're concerned specifically with the implementation efficiency/elegance of your code, maybe consider Code Review, instead?

Comment: @TylerH I don't think this would fare very well on Code Review, unless they posted all the code, instead of just a few lines. It would likely get closed as "stub code". Thanks for recommending us though!

Comment: @Phrancis I didn't realize CR required 100% of an application's code. That's... scary.

Comment: @TylerH We don't require a whole application's code by any means, but usually people post at least a class or two, or in this case, perhaps the whole HTML file in question and CSS class, perhaps any outside JavaScript that is related, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this using the following method:

Header file:

```
<a href="#/home" data-ng-class="{ active : activeController == 'HomeCtrl' }">Home</a>
```

App.js

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(ev,data) {

        if (data.$$route && data.$$route.controller) {
            $rootScope.activeController = data.$$route.controller;
        }
    });
});
```

This will create a variable `activeController` in the root scope any time a route change occurs and then use that variable to set the `active` class

Comment: Nice! I just did this and it worked. And it fixed another issue: the Main button is highlighted when the app starts. Before, that didn't happen until you clicked on it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a `$rootScope.links` array, each item in it being an object of the various pages on your site. Thus:

```
[{name: 'Home', URL: 'home', order: 1}, {name: 'Recipes', URL: 'recipes', order: 2}, ...]
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="link in links | orderBy:order" ng-class={{'active': activePath === link.path}}>
        <a ng-href="#!/{{link.path}}">{{link.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In your script:

```
.run(function ($location, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.activePath = '';

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
        var pathArray = $location.path().split('/');

        $rootScope.activePath = pathArray[1];
    });
});
```